# 1st occurrence of any digit/number in a string with out loops

Tags: c, string, loops

I have a string,assume

```
char *Wstr = "TEMP =20C ALT=12D"
char *temp_pos = NULL;
char *tpos = NULL;
char temp[10] = {'\0'};
```

I'm trying to obtain the value 20 and store it.
The spacing between `TEMP` and `20C` may be inconsistent i.e:
`TEMP=20C` or `TEMP = 20C` or `TEMP =20C` or `TEMP= 20C`.
Currently I do a call to `strstr` for `TEMP` and then use while loop in conjunction with `isdigit`:

```
if ((temp_pos = strstr(Wstr, "TEMP"))) {
   tpos = temp_pos+4;

   while(isspace(*tpos) || (*tpos == '='))
      tpos++;
   while ((isdigit(*tpos)) && (*tpos!='\0')) {
      temp[i] = *tpos;
      i++;
      tpos++;
   }
}
```

Is there a way that I could right away get the number i.e in this case 20 after the `strstr`, I want to minimize the number of loops in my code, is there a better way to do it i.e a better way to write this code/logic?

Comment: Why don't you search for first `=` instead of `TEMP`?

Comment: The string that I have listed is a part of a larger string some thing like:  LAT=xyz LONG=yyyy etc..... TEMP = 20C

Comment: maybe he wants to find "TEMP     =                       20", and the string can contain other equations.

Comment: Actually at the end of a day you cant avoid using iterations (loops).

Comment: Why do you want to obfuscate your code? Concentrate on writing readable&maintainable code. Loops are not worse than other statements. Use what is natural for the problem.

Comment: @xing thanks! that worked!! :)

Comment: thanks! would put a check for same in the code

Comment: @xing, better use `strtoll` or so for string to number conversion.